# How to correct "bodyfont '15pt' is defined (can better be done global)" error in ConTeXt?

Tags: fontsize, context

I have a document that I want to optimize for viewing on an eink reader. As such, I need the font to be larger, setting the default size to 15 pt. The other items on the page, such as subscript text, is scaled relative to this size. I used the following code:

```
\definefontfamily [sourcehansans] [sans] [sourcehansanssclight][features=chinese]
\definefontfamily [sourcehansans] [math] [modern]
\setupbodyfont [sourcehansans,ss,15pt]
\starttext
    This is a test.
\stoptext
```

This produces a PDF with the desire appearance, but when I compile this code, however, I get this warning:

```
bodyfont '15pt' is defined (can better be done global)
```

For long documents, this error will print thousands of times.

How can I correct my code, so that the default font size is 15 points, but so that this error does not appear?

Comment: Note that an error is not the same as a warning. Is it a warning or an error?

Comment: It continues to compile, so I think it is a warning. Nonetheless, this means maybe my code is incorrect. What is the "global" way that the warning suggests I use?

Comment: Does http://context.aanhet.net/svn/contextman/context-reference/en/co-fonts.pdf help? Can you reproduce with a standard font other people will have? If it is font specific, can you provide a link?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get rid of the size warning use

```
\definebodyfontenvironment[15pt]
```

But then your font definitions are still wrong.  To use synonyms like `modern` you have to use `\definetypeface`.  Then it is better to pack it all in a dedicated typescript.

```
\starttypescript[sourcehansans]
  \definetypeface [\typescriptone] [rm] [serif] [modern]               [default] [features=default]
  \definetypeface [\typescriptone] [ss] [sans]  [sourcehansanssclight] [default] [features=chinese]
  \definetypeface [\typescriptone] [tt] [mono]  [modern]               [default] [features=none]
  \definetypeface [\typescriptone] [mm] [math]  [modern]               [default]
\stoptypescript

\definebodyfontenvironment[15pt]

\setupbodyfont [sourcehansans,ss,15pt]

\starttext
    This is a test.
\stoptext
```

This will still issue a warning

```
fonts           > typescripts > unknown library 'sourcehansanssclight'
```

You have to define a typescript for `sourcehansanssclight` like

```
\starttypescript [sans] [sourcehansanssclight]
  \definefontsynonym [Sans]            [file:...]
  \definefontsynonym [SansBold]        [file:...]
  \definefontsynonym [SansItalic]      [file:...]
  \definefontsynonym [SansBoldItalic]  [file:...]
  \definefontsynonym [SansSlanted]     [file:...]
  \definefontsynonym [SansBoldSlanted] [file:...]
\stoptypescript
```

where you fill in the correct filenames for the dots.